# AWS Route 53 CNAME

Tags: amazon-route53, laravel-forge

This has to be simple. I have an A record that points to my server just fine. However, I just added a CNAME for a "www".website.com that points to website.com, but it is now just returning an Nginx 404 error. For reference, I'm using Laravel Forge to deploy the server and of course AWS Route 53 for DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I want to post an answer in case anyone comes across this issue like I did. I was unaware that this can be solved by configuring the Nginx config file and through Laravel Forge, it's pretty easy.

On my server, I have 2 sites (one pointing to site.com and one pointing to www.site.com). In my DNS provider (AWS Route 53), I have an A record for each URL and both point to the public IP of my server.

So, I go into the Nginx config (through Laravel Forge) for the site I want to redirect (in this case I want to go from www to non-www) and edit the config file to include the following.

```
 server_name www.site.com;
 return 301 $scheme://site.com$request_uri;
```

Works perfectly now!